# Matching plain text between limiters with Regex (parsing todo.txt)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to parse todo.txt format with Python and regex.

The format for todo.txt is here https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt

A rundown of what specifies different tags are:

1. Projects are matched by finding words preceded with +
2. Contexts are matched with @
3. Meta Data is a key:value pair
4. Priorities are matched with bracketed letters (A) for example
5. Tasks are marked as complete when there is an "x" at the start
6. Dates are in yyyy-mm-dd format

So far I can extract all of these with groups via the following regex pattern

`(?P<context>[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<Project>[+][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(?P<meta>[a-zA-Z]*:[A-Za-z0-9\-]*)?(?P<priority>\(.\))?(?P<complete>^[x])?(?P<Date>\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d)?(?P<task>)`

What I can't match, is the task itself.

Any help is massively appreciated.

A link to my efforts is at: https://regex101.com/r/ega8dQ/1

There are a good few combinations of what should match in there if that helps.

[image: The text I'm trying to capture]

I've created a group called task that I'm hoping to capture all of the task names. I've tried capturing all [A-Za-z] with a lookahead and a lookbehind but I'm just not getting how to do it.

I've been trying to do this since yesterday and have gone through books and endless searches without being able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Either it matches individual letters or matches everything and I lose my groups for the other aspects like +project @context etc

Comment: You have lots of optional groups there. Regarding the arbitrary nesting of components into each other you will probably need to use alternation. Here is [some demo I played with](https://regex101.com/r/VoGecP/1) from that parts might help. Still wondering how you would separate each task from the other.

Comment: That's really helpful and exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you. With regards to separating each task from the other, I was thinking of parsing it with the regex like this and readline with Python to break at each new line. The spec for todo.txt states that every task must be on a new line. Going to have a play now. Thanks again Bobble bubble :-D

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please also provide several example inputs and indicate exactly what is to be matched/captured as groups.

Comment: First post on Stackoverflow and all expectations have been met. Thanks ;-)